# Pandas Dataframe df.at KeyError

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes and the excel I use for it has three sheets. `SQL / Bio / Gen`. In Bio and Gen are two different types of `IDs (Labornumber) 191****** and 192******`. Both frames have the layout from the SQL sheet.

SQL:

```
OrderID     Creation Date   User ID Days in Lab Gender  Sample Date ID of Sample Card   System Sample ID    OrderStatus         Sample Received Sample Rejected Genetics    Closed Enzyme testing only  Closed Enzyme + genetic testing Closed genetic testing only Closed biomarker testing only   Closed Enzyme / Lyso pending    Closed Enzyme + Lyso testing    Department  City    Country     Signed ICF  ICF Agreement       Pompe   Status biochemical test Result biochemical test Status genetic test Result genetic test Gaucher Status biochemical test Result biochemical test Status genetic test Result genetic test Niemann-Pick    Status biochemical test Result biochemical test Status genetic test Result genetic test Fabry   Is a family mutation known  Status biochemical test Result biochemical test Status biomarker test   Result biomarker test   Status genetic test Result genetic test MPS I   Status biochemical test Result biochemical test Status genetic test Result genetic test MPS II  Status biochemical test Result biochemical test MPS VI  Status biochemical test Result biochemical test Lyso-GL-3: alpha-galactosidase  Status biochemical test Result biochemical test
329819      2017-01-02      954569  4           Gender  2017-12-05  11112345            329819              REPORT_AVAILABLE    2017-01-09      NO              2017-01-23  2017-01-23                  2017-01-23                      2017-01-23                  2017-01-23                      2017-01-23                      2017-01-23                      Department  City    Country     Y           disease diagnostic  0       0                       0                       0                   0                   0       0                       0                       0                   0                   0               0                       0                       0                   0                   0       0                           0                       0                       0                       0                       0                   0                   0       0                       0                       0                   0                   0       0                       0                       0       0                       0                       0                               0                       0
```

Bio:

```
Barcode     Eingangsdatum       Befunddatum Biochemie   Befunddatum Biochemie2  Befunddatum Lyso-GL-1   Biochemie Ergebnis  Biochemie Ergebnis2 Ergebnis Lyso-GL-1  Biochemistry report Diagnosis   Diagnosis_2 Labornummer Age     Sex Country
91429483    2017-12-05 00:00:00 09.01.2017                                                              3,191109194                                                 normal              MPS Panel               192000200   14      Sex Country
```

Gen:

```
Date of Genetic Report  Barcode     Date for starting genetic testing   klin Diagnose   klin Diagnose2  Alter   Sex Labornummer Country     Biochemie Ergebnis  Biochemie Ergebnis2 Lyso-GL-1   Gene-ID Mutation AS 1   Mutation AS 2   Mutation Codon1 Mutation Codon2 Mutationsart    Mutationsart 1  Mutationsart 2  Family
2017-01-25 00:00:00     51425126    2017-01-11 00:00:00                 Fabry           Lyso-GL3        30      Sex 192000250   Country     2,432291667         3,794916415                     BAC                                                                     normal
```

Data2 should only have 192 numbers and data1 191.
For data2 all 192 numbers are in the SQL sheet. In gen there are 191 and 192 numbers so I filter it with

```
regex = re.compile(r"(?!191\d*)")

for index, row in self.data1.iterrows():
    if(re.match(regex, str(row["Labornummer"]))):
        self.data1.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

This works very well and I have all 191 in my data1 dataframe.
After that I merge data1 with all information I get from gen and bio with the `Labnumber`

The same for data2 but I merge it with the Barcode / System Sample ID

That works, every frame has all his data I need to change the cells in it.

Data1 with the problem has 7387 rows and 96 columns. I iterat through every row and save the index I want to change later. This is working fine, but if I want to  change the value in specific cells with the indices I saved in a list, I get the error `KeyError: 6817`

The function to save the index I want to change later:

```
for index, row in self.data1.iterrows():
        if row["Diagnosis"] == "Disease":
            if self.getCutOffResult(row["Result"], row["Diagnosis"]):
                b_Disease_pos_1.append(index)
```

The function to change a value in a specific cell:

```
for index in container:   
                    if self.isSecondRequest(index):
                        self.data1.at[index, row] = 2
                    else:
                        self.data1.at[index, row] = 1
```

Both functions changes data1 and data2, but I don't have a problem with data2 only with data1 and from my side data1 shouldn't have a problem because the indices exist, I see it in the dataframe and in the excel after I export it with pandas. I loop through every row so it must exist.

Dataframe:

```
     OrderID Creation Date User ID Days in Lab  Gender Sample Date  ID of Sample Card System Sample ID  ...
7386     NaN    1999-01-14     NaN         NaN  Male         NaN         000000000000              NaN  ...
[7387 rows x 96 columns]
```

Comment: Not clear. Please add the csv or excel you are using and what operation you are willing to perform. t will help us to answer properly.

Comment: Maybe you could give us [mcve]? Create an example of your input, steps you take and output you'd like to get.